# IBM Watson visual recognition c#

Tags: c#, ibm-watson

I'm trying to develop an ASP.Net app ( software app or the web) in visual studio 2013 OR 2015 that uses IBM Watson Visual Recognition service.

I have seen the examples for QA service but it is outdated with the Watson credentials and functionality.
the example: (it requires username and password as credentials, which are not supplied anymore when creating a service):

http://www.nechai.net/2016/07/05/invoking-the-web-api-of-ibm-watsons-speech-to-text-service-from-net/

This example that I have found looks updated to today's credentials ( the API Key instead of username and pass) but I can't import, open or use the sub projects inside it, visual studio does not know how to recognize it)
"https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/visual-recognition-aspnet"

the two inner projects that the project rely on are VisualRecognition and WatsonServices projects in the main project.
They have a project file with the xproj extension file, which visual studio 2013 AND 2015 seems to not recognize so I can't try it or reuse its code in my test app.

the above example project is too complicated to just grab the code and try it (after failing to import and making it work on VS 2013)

Is there a very simple example on how to connect to a watson service using this type of credentials? :

"credentials": {
"url": "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api",
"note": "It may take up to 5 minutes for this key to become active",
"api_key": "********************************************************"
}

I have also tried to install the Watson services SDK by Nuget and by downloading the source and opening it in VS (for visual recognition specifically and the whole services option as well) but with no luck as well.
When opening the source code in VS, it says "incompatible" with all the files.
"https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk"

When trying to install with Nuget I get Errors:
in VS2013:
Install-Package: Could not install package 'IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.VisualRecognition.v3 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFram
ework,Version=v4.6', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.VisualRecognition.v3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

in VS 2015:
Install-Package : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3' from source 'd:\Users*****\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\FaceDetection\packages'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.VisualRecognition.v3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

There is no example on how to use or install the SDKs except for using Nuget so I'm lost here.

Answer (score 1):

The Watson Developer Cloud .NET Standard SDK has been updated to 1.1.0. Please try to update the packages. You can see examples of how to invoke the service in the [readme](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk/tree/development/src/IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.VisualRecognition.v3) for the service.

Additionally, there is an [example file](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/dotnet-standard-sdk/blob/development/examples/IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.VisualRecognition.v3.Example/VisualRecognitionServiceExample.cs) of how to invoke the service in the examples directory of the github repo.

Basically you instantiate the service

```
private VisualRecognitionService _visualRecognition = new VisualRecognitionService();
```

Set the credentials

```
_visualRecognition.SetCredential(apikey);
```

And call the API (`classify` in this example)

```
var result = _visualRecognition.Classify(<image-url>);
```

You should be able to traverse the result object to get the classification results

```
if (result != null)
{
    foreach (ClassifyTopLevelSingle image in result.Images)
        foreach (ClassifyPerClassifier classifier in image.Classifiers)
            foreach (ClassResult classResult in classifier.Classes)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("class: {0} | score: {1} | type hierarchy: {2}", classResult._Class, classResult.Score, classResult.TypeHierarchy));
}
```

You can also see the result in json format by serializing the result object

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, Formatting.Indented));
```